# Apache Allow or Redirect users

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I'm trying to use a **.htaccess** to Redirect people that are not from a certain IP range.
Redirect is working ok, but I can't figure out how to do both at the same time:
- People within a certain range: access to content
- People outside of this range: get redirected somewhere else

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried mod_rewrite?  For example,

http://blog.e-shell.org/25

Comment: looks really great this article. I've never found an article dealing with IP and Rewriting. Many thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped.  :)